# D concurrent writing to buffer

Tags: concurrency, buffer, d

Say you have a buffer of size N which must be set to definite values (say to zero, or something else). This value setting in the buffer is divided over M threads, each handling N / M elements of the buffer.

The buffer cannot be `immutable`, since we change the values. Message passing won't work either, since it is forbidden to pass ref or array (= pointer) types. So it must happen through `shared`? No, since in my case the buffer elements are of type `creal` and thus arithmetics are not atomic.

At the end, the main program must wait until all threads are finished. It is given that each thread only writes to a subset of the array and none of the threads have overlap in the array with another thread or in any way depend on eachother.

How would I go about writing to (or modifying) a buffer in a concurrent manner?

PS: sometimes I can simply divide the array in M consecutive pieces, but sometimes I go over the array (the array is 1D but represents 2D data) column-by-column. Which makes the individual arrays the threads use be actually interleaved in the mother-array. Argh.

---

EDIT: I figured out that the type `shared(creal)[]` would work, since now the elements are shared and not the array itself. You could parallelize interleaved arrays I bet. There is some disadvantage though:

The `shared` storage class is so strict, that the allocation must be supplied with the keyword. Which makes it hardly encapsulated; since the caller must supply the array, it is obligated to pass a `shared` array and can't just generically pass a regular array and let the processing function worry about parallelism. No, the calling function must worry about parallelism too, so that the processing function receives a shared array and needn't reallocate the array into `shared` space.

<strike>There is also a very strange bug, that when I dynamically allocate `shared(creal)[]` at certain spots, it simply hangs at allocation. Seems very random and can't find the culprit...
In the test example this works, but not in my project...</strike> *This turned out to be a bug in DMD / OptLink.*

---

EDIT2: I never mentioned, but it's for implementing the FFT (Fast Fourier Theorem). So I have no power over selecting precise cache aligned slices. All I know is the elements are of type creal and the number of elements is a power of 2 (per row / column).

Comment: What you are trying sounds more like parallelism than concurrency. You may take a look into std.parallelism: http://www.d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_parallelism.html

Comment: Just a meta-comment: if read/write on the array is a possible bottleneck, try to size your slices so they align with cache-line boundaries. Otherwise the threads will clobber each other's caches, and you could see a noticeable performance drop.

Comment: @gmfawcett:  Or, possibly more simply, just make the work units big enough that the cache lines that are shared between threads are a small fraction of the total cache lines used.

Comment: Could you pass a message containing an slice of the array? Dirty casts would let you subvert the type system if needed.

Comment: It turns out parallelism and concurrency std libs can both be used in this problem.

Comment: @dsimcha: good point, and I agree it's simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [std.parallelism](http://www.d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_parallelism.html) module

```
T[] buff;
foreach(ref elem;parallel(buff))elem=0;
```

but if you want to reinvent this you can just use shared (it is thread safe to only let 1 thread accesses a certain element at the time and if you enforce this with the appropriate `join()` or `Task.*force()` so much the better)