# D taskpool wait untill all tasks are done

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, task, d, wait

This is in relation to my previous question: [D concurrent writing to buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330701/d-concurrent-writing-to-buffer)

Say you have a piece of code that consists of 2 consecutive code blocks A and B, where B depends on A. This is very common in programming. Both A and B consist of a loop, where each iteration can be run in parallel:

```
double[] array = [ ... ]; // has N elements

// A
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    job1(array[i]); // new task
}

// wait for all job1's to be done

// B
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    job2(array[i]); // new task
}
```

B can only be executed when A is finished. How do I wait till all tasks of A are finished before executing B?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you're using std.parallelism?  I wrote std.parallelism, so I'll let you in on a design decision.  There was actually a `join` function in some of the betas of std.parallelism.  It waited until all tasks were finished and then shut down the task pool.  I removed it because I realized it was useless.

The reason is that if you're manually creating a set of O(N) `task` objects to iterate over some range, you're misusing the library.  You should be using a parallel foreach loop instead, which automatically joins before it releases control back to the calling thread.  Your example would become:

```
foreach(ref elem; parallel(array)) {
    job1(elem); 
}

foreach(ref elem; parallel(array)) {
    job2(elem);
}
```

In this case `job1` and `job2` should not start a new task because the parallel foreach loop is already using enough tasks to fully utilize all CPU cores.

Comment: I can see your point. However what if we want to iterate over things that is not so straight forward using foreach? What if you want to iterate over the odd indices? Would I need to build a new array so I can use foreach? There is scopedTask which does almost what I need, except it's scoped to the iteration, not the loop as a whole...

Comment: @Daevius:  If you want to iterate over odd indices, you could use std.range.stride or foreach(i; parallel(std.range.iota(1, array.length, 2)).  std.parallelism was created with the assumption that this kind of flexibility would be provided by the higher order ranges in std.algorithm and std.range instead of having to plan for it explicitly in the design of std.parallelism.

Comment: Yes indeed, due to the many facilities of range creation, this is a neat design. Got a speed increase of ~200% with my 2D FFT algo on a quad core :), thanks. Btw, does iota really relate to the greek letter Iota? ^^

Comment: @Daevius Not at all. The name comes from C++'s `iota` function as it does essentially the same thing. However, the name really has _nothing_ to do with what it actually does. I have no idea why it was chosen for C++. Many people do not like the name, because it really makes no sense, but it _is_ consistent with C++, and it's memorable.